# What is the best way to statically initialize an EnumMap in Java

Tags: java, enums, static, enum-map

I need to statically initialize an EnumMap. I know two ways.

1. Using of() method of Map

   ```java
   private static final Map<<EnumKey>, <Value>> TEST_MAP = Map.of(ENUM_CONST1, "Value1", ENUM_CONST2, "Value2");
   ```
2. Using double brace initialization

   ```java
   private static final Map<<EnumKey>, <Value>> TEST_MAP = new EnumMap<>(EnumKey.class) {
       {
           put(ENUM_CONST1, "Value1");
           put(ENUM_CONST2, "Value2");
        }
   };
   ```

Is there any other cleaner and more efficient way?

Comment: second one is a big anti-pattern and your first one does not initialize an `EnumMap`, but a `Map` (immutable one)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A neat way to setup EnumMap is to define all the values in-line using `Map.of` or `Map.ofEntries` but note that this allocates a Map before the EnumMap constructor:

```
private static final EnumMap<YourEnum,String> A = new EnumMap<>(Map.of(
        YourEnum.ONE, "Value1",
        YourEnum.TWO, "Value2"
));

// Use Map.ofEntries for enums with more than 10 values:
private static final EnumMap<YourEnum,String> B = new EnumMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(YourEnum.ONE, "Value1"),
        Map.entry(YourEnum.TWO, "Value2")
));
```

If wanting public access then wrap as unmodifiable Map (which is backed by EnumMap) or just pass back `Map.of` directly (but is not using an EnumMap).

```
public static final Map<YourEnum,String> C = Collections.unmodifiableMap(B);
```

Answer (score 3):

do it in a static block:

```
private static final EnumMap<....> yourMap = ...

static {
   yourMap.put(....);
   yourMap.put(....)
}
```

There will be ways to do this rather differently (but they don't exist in the API yet), via `Constant Dynamic`.

Comment: any specific reason of doing it in static block?

Comment: @sham how else?

Comment: the first one also looks good. Is it better to do with static block

Comment: Thanks got the answer. 
"Note that this Map.of method supports only a maximum of 10 key-value pairs."
mention it in your article - https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashmap

Comment: yeah agree...I was talking about `Map.of`

which can store max of 10 mapping which is overcome with the `ofEntries`

Comment: @sham A specific reason to use it could be to only have access to Java 8. Map.of() was introduced with Java 9.

Comment: hmm, static block or static method is the only way to do it in java 8

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a method:

```
private static final EnumMap<....> yourMap = yourMapMethod();

private static EnumMap<....> yourMapMethod() {
   EnumMap<....> yourMap = ...
   yourMap.put(....);
   yourMap.put(....);
   return yourMap;
}
```